# Is it possible to have conditional arguments in terraform resources

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to setup a datasync in AWS with a schedule however i only need the schedule in 2 environments, is there a way you can have conditional arguments so that the schedule is only set in dev and test.

```
resource "aws_datasync_task" "data-load" {
  destination_location_arn = aws_datasync_location_s3.destination.arn
  name                     = "data-load"
  source_location_arn      = aws_datasync_location_nfs.source.arn

  schedule {
    schedule_expression = "cron(0 12 ? * SUN,WED *)"
  }
}
```

I tried

```
  schedule {
    schedule_expression = var.data_sync_schedule
  }


variables.tf:

variable "data_sync_schedule" {
  default = null
}

dev and test tfvars:

data_sync_schedule = "cron(0 8 * * ? *)"
```

but for all other envs other than dev test i get the following error:

```
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   with aws_datasync_task.data-load[0],
│   on data-sync.tf line 19, in resource "aws_datasync_task" "data-load":
│   19:     schedule_expression = var.data_sync_schedule
│ 
│ The argument "schedule.0.schedule_expression" is required, but no
│ definition was found.
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to null out the schedule expression, you need to make the entire `aws_datasync_task` resource conditional. You can do that with the [count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html) argument on the resource, setting it to either `0` or `1`.

Comment: I still need the data sync in other environments i just don't want them to run on a schedule

Comment: Then you need to make the `schedule` block a dynamic block. https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
resource "aws_datasync_task" "data-load" {
  destination_location_arn = aws_datasync_location_s3.destination.arn
  name                     = "data-load"
  source_location_arn      = aws_datasync_location_nfs.source.arn

  schedule {
    schedule_expression = var.env == 'dev' ? "cron(0 12 ? * SUN,WED *)" : null
  }
}
```

Var.env would be set via your CI/CD job